# adding client events to telerik drop down list makes it static

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, telerik, telerik-mvc

I am trying to add client events to a telerik dropdownlist, but doing so makes it  static. By static I mean it doesnt behave as a dropdown list anymore, Its doesnt respond when I click and hence cant view/select values. But as soon as I change the dropdown list to a combobox it works perfectly fine. It lets me click and view/select values.

Why is this happening? why can I add client events to a telerik combobox but not to a telerik dropdown list?

Here is how I populate Combo Box:

```
        <%= Html.Telerik().ComboBox().Name("ComboBox")
            .HtmlAttributes(new { @id = "ComboBox", @style = "width:104px;" })
            .ClientEvents(events =>
        {
            events.OnDataBinding("ComboBox_onDataBinding");
        })%>  

function ComboBox_onDataBinding(e) {
    var comboBox = $('#ComboBox').data('tComboBox');
                comboBox.dataBind([
                    { Text: "Product 1", Value: "1" },
                    { Text: "Product 2", Value: "2", Selected: true },
                    { Text: "Product 3", Value: "3" },
                    { Text: "Product 4", Value: "4" },
                    { Text: "Product 5", Value: "5" }
                ], true);
};
```

Here is how I populate drop-down list:

```
        <%= Html.Telerik().DropDownList().Name("DropDownList")
            .HtmlAttributes(new { @id = "DropDownList", @style = "width:104px;" })
            .ClientEvents(events =>
        {
            events.OnDataBinding("DropDownList_onDataBinding");
        })%>  

function DropDownList_onDataBinding(e) {
    var dropDownList = $('#DropDownList').data('tDropDownList');
                dropDownList.dataBind([
                    { Text: "Product 1", Value: "1" },
                    { Text: "Product 2", Value: "2", Selected: true },
                    { Text: "Product 3", Value: "3" },
                    { Text: "Product 4", Value: "4" },
                    { Text: "Product 5", Value: "5" }
                ], true);
};
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: could it be because your components are backwards? you have `.DropDownList().Name("ComboBox")` and `.ComboBox().Name("DropDownList")`

Comment: @ob. Sorry, it was a miss type. The issue still exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case, when you don't use Ajax or WebService client side databinding, you shouldn't configure OnDataBinding event handler. You need to configure OnLoad instead:

```
.ClientEvents(events => events.OnLoad("ddl_onLoad").OnChange("ddl_onChange")
```

handlers:

```
function ddl_onLoad(e) {

    var ddl = $(this).data('tDropDownList');

    ddl.dataBind([
        { Text: 'Product 1', Value: '1' },
        { Text: 'Product 2', Value: '2', Selected: true },
        { Text: 'Product 3', Value: '3' },
        { Text: 'Product 4', Value: '4' }
    ], true);
}

function ddl_onChange(e) {

    //var ddl = $(this).data('tDropDownList');
    console.log(e.value);
}
```

Comment: Doesnt matter how I add client events, as soon as I add a client event to telerik ddl, it becomes statis(cant view/select values when I click on it). I tried your way, still doesnt work :/

Comment: Note - It works perfectly fine once I change it to a telerik combo box

Comment: Try to remove declaration of "id" attribute from the DropDownList (.HtmlAttributes(new { @id = "DropDownList", ...). This assignes id='DropDownList' attribute to a different html element.

Comment: That was it! :) Finally Thanks @Rustam

Comment: How did you think about this?

Answer (score 0):

you're calling `.dataBind()` inside the `OnDataBinding` handler, which is just going to trigger the `OnDataBinding` event again, and again...

consider doing your client side databinding inside the `OnLoad` event or something

Comment: doesn't matter which event I add. As soon as I add a client event and a JS function for that event telerik drop-down list becomes static. I tried OnLoad, OnChange, OnDataBinding, OnDataBound all of them

Comment: @user793468 any chance you have more than one drop down with the same name?

Comment: No, I double checked, even changed it to a different name and tried.